# Angular API requests for models with relationships to other models on id

Tags: angular, model, normalization, angular-httpclient

Let's say I have arrays as below:

```
Students = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Sara",
    schoolId: 1,
    carId: 3,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    ...
  },
]

School = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Some college",
    location: "Somewhere",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    ...
  },
]

Car = [
  {
    id: 3,
    make: "",
    model: ""
  }
]
```

API Service:

```
getStudents() {
  return this.http.get<Student[]>(this.studentUrl);
}
```

As I am to do a GET request to `Students` like above, I would only get the ids: `schoolId` and `carId`. What is the proper way to link these two properties to the actual object from the other two object lists so that the result from `getStudents()` would return something like below and be able to call `student.schoolId.name` in the HTML?

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Sara",
    schoolId: {
      id: 1,
      name: "Some college",
      location: "Somewhere",
    },
    carId: {
      id: 3,
      make: "",
      model: ""
    }
}
```

I've looked into mapping and `flatmap` but I was not sure if this was the way to go. I am basing these objects on what the database data would send. The `schoolId` and `carId` columns contain the id that link the id from the School and Car table.

Comment: This step needs to be done on the server side, something like sql relationship, or you need to fetch each table and merge the data on client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you work in the back-end service to return the data with the associated entity(s) as mentioned in the comment, or you can work with [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) to send responses to grab multiple data. After the observables are completed, use the [`map`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map) to transform data as below:

```
export interface Student {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  schoolId: number;
  carId: number;
}

export interface School {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  location: string;
}

export interface Car {
  id: number;
  make: string;
  model: string;
}

export interface StudentWithSchoolCarData extends Student {
  school: School;
  car: Car;
}
```

```
getStudentsWithSchoolCarData(): Observable<StudentWithSchoolCarData[]> {
  return forkJoin([
    this.http.get<Student[]>(this.studentUrl),
    this.http.get<School[]>(this.schoolUrl),
    this.http.get<Car[]>(this.carUrl),
  ]).pipe(
    map(([students, schools, cars]: any[]) => {
      return students.map((x: Student) => ({
        ...x,
        school: schools.find((y: School) => y.id == x.schoolId),
        car: cars.find((y: Car) => y.id == x.carId),
      }));
    })
  );
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fjjezk?file=src%2Fstudents.service.ts)

Comment: I see. I went with your answer and also used mergemap to forkjoin more objects. I think it is most ideal to be able to get this structure from the backend first, so I will work on that. Thanks for the solution!